# HTTPS POST request in Java on ASP.NET website

Tags: java, url, urlencode

I am unable to post a request in a asp.net website.
When I tried in localhost on php its worked fine but on the web asp.net website its not working .

Please some one help me out.

```
    package cc.cu.desertcreator;

    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;

    public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Construct data
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("__EVENTTARGET", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode("", "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("__EVENTARGUMENT", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode("", "UTF-8");

            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("__VIEWSTATE", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode("/wEPDwUJMjQ4Njc3OTkzD2QWAmYPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWCGYPZBYGAgEPZBYCAgMPFgIeC18hSXRlbUNvdW50Av////8PZAIDDxYCHgdjb250ZW50BRIxMjAzMjAzOTYxLDM2MDYzNTJkAgQPFQENJ1VBLTcxODc2MC0xJ2QCBg8WAh4HVmlzaWJsZWhkAgcPDxYCHwJoZGQCCA9kFgICAQ9kFgICARBkZBYCAgEPZBYCAgkPZBYCZg9kFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgICAw8PFgIeEkVuYWJsZUNsaWVudFNjcmlwdGhkZGRPA99uYkD6em3jusGYVPJ/ioe47g==", "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("userPrefs", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode("", "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("M$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$MainContent$eh", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");
            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("M$ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$MainContent$c7$tb_email", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode("asikpstu@gmail.com", "UTF-8");
            // Send data
            URL url = new URL("https://www.prosper.com/account/common/login.aspx");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            wr.close();
            rd.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

The output should goto net page source but it returns:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://m.prosper.com/account/common/login.aspx">here</a></h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: would you please give some advise instead of negative mark on my question.....:(

Comment: Looks like a hack to me, you try to enter the site (that you have forget the url on the code)

Comment: no no its not I just want to see my account status from my java application.

Comment: You can't do that unless several security settings on the target site are off (I hope for the target site that they are not). Anyway, here you are not even hitting that problem but seem to be redirected to the mobile version of the site (user agent matter maybe)